# Recruiting agency asked me to find a family member fill in I-9

Tags: job-offer, united-states, recruitment

I am a recent graduate and was offered a position at a scientific company though a recruiting agency. Although I will be doing work for the scientific company, I will technically be an employee of the recruiting agency. This situation is fairly standard in the field for recent graduates, but there is obvious room for abuse so I have been on the look out for red flags.

A few days ago the agency sent me an email explaining the I9 form. They said I had to fill in section one and *a family member or friend* must do section two. They said the person I picked would be acting as a representative of the agency so everything is legal. When I pressed them about this, they linked to [this](https://verifyi9remote.com/authorized-representative-form-i9-remote-hires/) article.

I have two questions:

- First, is this situation a red flag?
- Second, is it illegal, and if so who should I contact about it?

Comment: Would you care to explain what an I9 is for the rest of the world to understand your question?

Answer (score 5):

Surprisingly, this looks legitimate.  There are more links that corroborate what you've been informed of:

[https://www.shrm.org/resourcesandtools/hr-topics/talent-acquisition/pages/how-to-complete-i9-verification-during-coronavirus-pandemic.aspx#:~:text=%22Under%20the%20circumstances%20raised%20by,and%20takes%20the%20responsibility%20seriously.%22](https://www.shrm.org/resourcesandtools/hr-topics/talent-acquisition/pages/how-to-complete-i9-verification-during-coronavirus-pandemic.aspx#:%7E:text=%22Under%20the%20circumstances%20raised%20by,and%20takes%20the%20responsibility%20seriously.%22)

https://www.dwt.com/blogs/employment-labor-and-benefits/2020/03/i9-new-hire-deadline-2020

Make sure your prospective employer is 100% legit before sending any docs!

Answer (score 2):

During the COVID heath crisis it wasn't unusual to be hiring people who would never be in the office. I had a relative who showed their I-9 related IDs over a web camera.

They worked for the company for 16 months and were never in the corporate or the government customers office. They were given their laptop, in the parking lot of the building. They never went inside. Their smart card used to get into the VPN was in the laptop bag. Their customer was fine with this method of giving them access.

The I-9 rules were relaxed during the crisis. They were not required to have handled the forms as part of the on-boarding process.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's legal. If you want complete coverage, though, talk to your bank and see if they have a notary who will help you with the process.